# How can I select DISTINCT rows for SUM()?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to run a report which will give me daily "plot" sales over the past 3 months and I'm having a hard time getting SUM() to add up correctly. A single Transaction_ID may span across several Plot records. With the query below, if there are 2 plots with the same Transaction_ID, it is adding them together, which is not what I want. I need it to only use a Transaction row once within the SUM().

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%m-%d') AS MonthAndDay, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%M, %D') AS Day, 
    SUM(Transactions.AmountTotal) AS DailySales 
FROM 
    Transactions, 
    Plots 
WHERE 
    Transactions.Transaction_ID = Plots.Transaction_ID AND 
    Transactions.CreateDate <= CURDATE() AND 
    Transactions.CreateDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY 
    MonthAndDay 
ORDER BY 
    MonthAndDay ASC
```

The table structures look like so:

```
+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                             | Type                                                                                               | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Transaction_ID                    | int(11)                                                                                            | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment | 
| CreateDate                        | datetime                                                                                           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                | 
| AmountTotal                       | decimal(10,2)                                                                                      | NO   |     | 0.00                |                | 
+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Plot_ID                | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment | 
| Transaction_ID         | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                | 
| Plot                   | varchar(10) | NO   |     | 0                   |                | 
+------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Don't you just want to `GROUP BY Plot_ID, MonthAndDay` ?

Comment: Doing that breaks the grouping by MonthDay, which is the point of the report, and it doesn't solve the issue of having the Transaction summed however many times it shows up in a Plot record (which is the main part of my original problem described above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works, albeit with a subquery:

```
SELECT
   DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%m-%d') AS MonthAndDay,
   DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%M, %D') AS Day,
   SUM(Transactions.AmountTotal) AS DailySales
FROM
   Transactions
WHERE
   Transactions.Transaction_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Transaction_ID FROM Plots) AND
   Transactions.CreateDate <= CURDATE() AND
   Transactions.CreateDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY
   MonthAndDay
ORDER BY
   MonthAndDay ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I think the following would work, but I haven't tested it, so could be wrong:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Transactions.Transaction_ID,
    DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%m-%d') AS MonthAndDay, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%M, %D') AS Day, 
    SUM(Transactions.AmountTotal) AS DailySales 
FROM 
    Transactions, 
    Plots 
WHERE 
    Transactions.Transaction_ID = Plots.Transaction_ID AND 
    Transactions.CreateDate <= CURDATE() AND 
    Transactions.CreateDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY 
    MonthAndDay 
ORDER BY 
    MonthAndDay ASC
```

Second go:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%m-%d') AS MonthAndDay, 
    DATE_FORMAT(Transactions.CreateDate,'%M, %D') AS DAY, 
    SUM(Transactions.AmountTotal) AS DailySales,
    COUNT(Transactions.Transaction_ID) AS Tmp
FROM 
    Transactions, 
    Plots
WHERE 
    Transactions.Transaction_ID = Plots.Transaction_ID AND 
    Transactions.CreateDate <= CURDATE() AND 
    Transactions.CreateDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
GROUP BY 
    Plots.Plot_ID, MonthAndDay 
ORDER BY 
    MonthAndDay ASC
```

This produced 3 rows in the Plots table, there two rows reference Transaction_ID 2 and one row references Transaction_ID 1

This resulted in three plot rows appearing, but with the sum values appearing correctly.

Comment: I'm still getting the same figures as my example query. My query is grouped by day, which I'm pretty sure is preventing that from having any affect.

Comment: Just to confuse matters... What is the purpose of the Plots table, if the data is not actually being used in the select, group or order by?

Comment: The Transaction table has other types of transactions in it, so the Plot table is used to only include transactions that were used to purchase plots. In addition, there is never a case where a transaction includes plots and something else.

Comment: Hmmm tricky... Instead of `SELECT DISTINCT Transactions.Transaction_ID,` does `SELECT DISTINCT Plots.Transaction_ID` help?

Comment: Good thought, but no cigar. Still getting the non-distinct SUM().

Comment: See my initial answer for another attempt ;)

Comment: The 2nd attempt is giving me multiple results per MonthAndDay.